# self killing shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, kill

I'm trying a simple test to kill a script from within its self.  It doesn't seem to be working.

```
function testKill
{
  PID=$$
  kill $PID
  echo  hello!
}
```

When I run this function,

```
[....]$ testKill
hello!
```

It clearly doesn't kill the process.  How do I make the process terminate before sending the echo command?

When I move this all into an external script, it terminates correctly if I call the script directly from the command line. However, if I make a function inside my .bash_profile and call the script from within that function, the script isn't killed and it prints instead. How do I integrate it into my .bash_profile?

**This is a minimal working example to use in a more complicated script.**

Comment: what if you add a `sleep 1` to give the signal handler chance to receive the signal before running the echo ?

Comment: First you script works just fine! 2. Why bother declaring PID and not just `kill $$`, this works and is A WHOLE LINE shorter!

Comment: @steve I should get delivered before kill returns, provided kill is a builtin (as it usually is).

Answer (score 6):

You haven't written a script in your example; it's a function. You're therefore applying the `kill` to your interactive shell session. Interactive shells ignore most signals, including the `SIGTERM` that you're sending.

Put the function and its call in a script and run that. It's far more likely to do what you expect.

Comment: I've moved this into an external script, and it terminates correctly if I call the script directly from the command line.  However, if I make a function inside my .bash_profile and call the script from within that function, the script isn't killed and it prints instead.  How do I integrate it into my .bash_profile?

Comment: @avikarto you asked how to kill a script from itself. The answer is `kill $$`, but it does not work on interactive shells. An interactive shell is not a script.

Answer (score 0):

try following, if you want to use it as function directly in bash, respectively sourced from console.

```
function testKill
{
  kill $PPID
  echo  "no hello :-/"
}
```